# x for listings that you dislike on careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

[angel.co](https://angel.co) has an interesting feature where each job listed **has an x button** (ie you say "disinterested" in a job).

The "disinterested" jobs go to *a separate list* (called the "Archive" there), so they don't clutter new search results, and they don't get in the way.  I think being able to 'x off' specific postings, so they don't appear to you again, would be nice.

The 'x' would unobtrusive and quiet, something like this:

[image]

Comment: Damn widget lovers.

Answer (score 2):

I like this idea, but not in the way it is listed.  I dislike this feature as is because it doesn't improve search as you are searching, but really only lets you archive away jobs.  If we were going to add this as a feature, I'd strongly recommend using `x` and job view data to build a model of what you're looking for and use that to create a better searching experience.  The reason I'd be so firm in this recommendation is because you only view job listings for a short time.  Just building up a data set doesn't improve the job seeker experience today.

Comment: _Yes_, it lets you archive away jobs so they don't appear again.  Kind of like being able to archive away email that you've already handled, and don't need to review again (unless you explicitly request it).

Comment: I think building a data model is a cool idea and logical step, but be hard to implement satisfactorily w/o surprising users ("Why can't I see job X?" "Because you archived job Y"..)

Comment: Also note in the Careers 2.0 ad window on SO, jobs you've already applied to still appear as if you haven't

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a sample demo of this feature in hacked JavaScript:

[image]

So hitting the 'x' moves the job into the **Archive** list, where you can still access it.  The Archive list probably wouldn't be exactly as shown, but you get the gist of it.

Here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMh2vGRfm8U) showing the feature.

And finally the JavaScript hack for Archive lists: (enter in Chrome console)

```
function randInt( v ) { return Math.floor((Math.random()*v)); }

body = $('body');
body.append( '<audio id="buzzer" src="http://redzombie.ca/buzz.wav" type="audio/wav"></audio>' ) ;

archive = $( '<div id="archive" style="position:absolute;top:110px;right:30px; width: 200px;background: white; padding: 10px; border: solid 1px #aaa;"><h1>Archive</h1>'+
'<ul id="archiveList" style="line-height:1.2em"></ul></div>' ) ;
body.prepend( archive ) ;

$('.list').children().each( function(){

  var jb = $(this) ;
  var x = $( '<span style="color: #aaa;position: absolute; right:0;top:0; cursor:pointer;">x</span>' ) ;
  jb.append( x ) ;
  x.click( function(evt){
    if( evt.target == x[0] )
    {
      $( '#buzzer' )[0].play() ;
      jb.animate({  color: "White",   backgroundColor: "White"   });
      var newLi = $( '<li>' + jb.find( '.employer' ).text() + ' &mdash; </li>' ) ;
      newLi.append( jb.find( '.job-link' ).first() ) ;
      archive.find( '#archiveList' ).append( newLi ) ;
      jb.remove();
    }
  } ) ;

} ) ;
```